# My javascript validation is displaying error

Tags: php, javascript, validation

I am trying to validate email and password with javascript in php .
but it is showing me error :-

```
{"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_lib', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0xa50990c>, 'html_name': 'js_lib', 'label': u'Js lib', 'field': <django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField object at 0xa69d64c>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_lib'}"}
```

my php code is

```
<form id="formLogin" name="formLogin" method="post" action=" " onsubmit="return validateForm()/">                   
                    <div class="divLogin">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td> Enter your Email: </td>
                                <td> <input type="text" name="txtEmail" required="required" autocomplete="off" /> </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td> Enter your Password:  </td>
                                <td> <input type="password" name="pwd" minlength="6" required="required" autocomplete="off" /> </td>
                            </tr>               
                        </table>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <input type="submit" class="btnLogin" value="Go" style="display:inline-block; margin-left:350px; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px;" />
                    </div>

                </form>
```

and my JS code is

```
function validateForm(){
var checkemail=document.forms["formLogin"]["txtEmail"].value;
var atpos=checkemail.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=checkemail.lastIndexOf(".");
var checkpwd=document.forms["formLogin"]["pwd"].value;  
if (checkemail==null){
    document.getElementById("checkemail").innerHTML = "Please Enter Email Address";
    return false;
}
if (checkpwd==null)
{
    document.getElementById("checkpwd").innerHTML = "Please Enter Password";
    return false;
}

if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=checkemail.length)
  {
  alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
  return false;
  }

if (checkpwd==null || checkpwd=="")
  {
  alert("Password must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: where are `checkemail` and `checkpwd` btw ?

Comment: @legendinmaking var checkemail=document.forms["formLogin"]["txtEmail"].value;
var checkpwd=document.forms["formLogin"]["pwd"].value;
in validateform in java script

Comment: I am asking for checkemail in `document.getElementById("checkemail")` section of your code ? Is it an div, span or any other HTML element and where are they ?

Comment: its a varible containing data from formlogin and textEmail id

Comment: `checkemail` and `checkpwd` needs to be an ID of any HTML element for this code to work !

Comment: @legendinmaking can you suggest any modification to work this code..can you edit it please

Comment: wait ... mmm.. try removing  **/** from `onsubmit="return validateForm()/"` may be that's the problem

Comment: try using `onsubmit="return validateForm()"` instead of `onsubmit="return validateForm()/"`

Comment: not working at all..i have deleted email @ and . operator check than it is working fine..so problem was in @ and dot operator checking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your form tag you have an extra  "/" after onsubmit function call

---

replace below line

```
<form id="formLogin" name="formLogin" method="post" action=" " onsubmit="return validateForm()/">
```

with

```
<form id="formLogin" name="formLogin" method="post" action=" " onsubmit="return validateForm()">
```

and one more thing your html5 "required" validator will respond first and then your validateForm function will be called.